# How to pass a variable through a selector?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, multithreading

I have a method

```
-(void)myMethod:(MyObject*)obj
```

And I am detaching a new thread

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(myMethod) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
```

How can I pass a MyObject* through @selector(myMethod)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(myMethod:) toTarget:self withObject:myObjectInstance];
```

You will definitely want that `@selector(myMethod:)` instead of `@selector(myMethod)`. They mean different things.

Comment: Should have seen the withObject parameter. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: More explicitly, the selector is the *name* of the message you're sending. The `:` is part of the method's name and thus part of the selector. You can have a method named `myMethod` and one named `myMethod:` live right alongside each other with no confusion — they're no more similar to the compiler than `kill` and `skill`. In fact, in Smalltalk (which Obj-C was based on), this is how getters and setters were normally written.